# How to reference to member group in doxygen

Tags: doxygen, documentation-generation

I have found how to give a group of class members a name:

```
/**\{
\name Foo
*/
 members
/**
\}*/
```

, but how do I reference to Foo from other class members?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
/** \{
\anchor Foo
\name   Foo
*/
members
/** \} */
```

The anchor allows you to refer to the group from elsewhere using

```
/// \ref Foo
```

Comment: This works but anchor is created after the Group name and brief description. so it appears in middle of the group content! Wish there is proper support for this

Answer (score 0):

No sure if naming a group is the same as defining one using `\defgroup id name` but with the latter you can `\ref` the id and it will link to the group's documentation.

Comment: It is not the same. `\defgroup` defines a [module](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#modules) whereas [member groups](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup) are started with `\name`.